# ActiveAdmin: Adding pages dynamically to the menu after the application has started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin as a CMS. I want my users to be able to create some pages and then these pages should be added dynamically in the active admin menu under a parent page called "Help". However, I can't workout how to register newly created pages, since the `register_page` method only runs when the server is started.

Is there a way to dynamically build the path to newly created pages? Or is there a way to run `register_page` dynamically (perhaps in a proc?) without having to restart?

Later edit:

The problem is the fact that I don't have a route for the newly created page so I get an error saying that `admin_page_title_path` could not be found after I create the page. This is because I'm doing a `register_page` in an `after_create`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Page do
  after_create do |page|
    ActiveAdmin.register_page page.title do
      menu :parent => 'Help'
      content :title => proc { I18n.t("active_admin.manual") } do
        columns do
          column do
            panel "#{raw(page.title)}" do
              render :partial => "admin/pages/content", :locals => {page: page}
            end
          end
        end #columns
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I use Rails.application.reload_routes! then the route is built, BUT this also clears my menus and I basically get a list of ALL the pages in the place where the menu used to be.

All the methods for rebuilding the menu that I tried seemed a bit hack-ish. So I assume there should be a way to rebuild just that one route instead of meddling with resetting resources and re-adding menu items.

Comment: could you add some examples of what you tried and what problems you faced.